# How do I subtract an odd row value from even row vlaue?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe below.
I want to even row value substract from odd row value.
and make new dataframe.

How can I do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'Time': [281.54385, 436.55295, 441.74910, 528.36445, 
                     974.48405, 980.67895, 986.65435, 1026.02485]}
data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
data
```

dataframe

```
    Time
0   281.54385
1   436.55295
2   441.74910
3   528.36445
4   974.48405
5   980.67895
6   986.65435
7   1026.02485
```

Wanted result

```
    ON_TIME
0   155.00910
1   86.61535
2   6.19490
3   39.37050
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use NumPy indexing:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(data.values[1::2] - data.values[::2], columns=['Time'])

print(res)

        Time
0  155.00910
1   86.61535
2    6.19490
3   39.37050
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use shift for the subtraction, and then pick every 2nd element, starting with the 2nd element (index = 1)

```
(data.Time - data.Time.shift())[1::2].rename('On Time').reset_index(drop=True)

outputs:

0    155.00910
1     86.61535
2      6.19490
3     39.37050
Name: On Time, dtype: float64
```